# How to add +1 in a specific column if date in another column = '2020-11-10' for example in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm working on a report that shows if a certain shipper performs as agreed - if they promised 1-day-delivery, it should be 1 day and not 2.

This is a screenshot of the table i created:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2kx2.png)

- Column 'transitdays_int' shows the difference between column 'shippingdate_date' and 'deliverydate_date' in days
- Column 'transit_treshold shows the number of days the shipper promised it would take to get it delivered
- In column 'success_ratio' i converted these values with a CASE-statement to 'on time' or 'late delivery'

Issue i have now is that i want to add +1 to column 'transit_treshold' if column 'shippingdate_date' = '2020-11-10'. Is that even possible? I read about many different solutions, but none of them seems to be exactly what i'm looking for...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images/links to images.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a report, you are just looking for a query and not to actually update the database values, correct?

If so, I would just update your query as:

```
select
    case when cast(shippingdate_date as date) = cast('2020-11-10' as date)
    then transit_treshold + 1
    else transit_treshold
    end as [Transit Days]
```

If you could provide your actual query it might be easier to help.

Also, what is special about 11/10/2020?  Are you looking for this date to be hard coded or do you need it to be dynamic?

Comment: Thanks @DataGuy! This did the trick, i did try that but i must have made a mistake somewhere. Very new to this ;) It shouldn't be dynamic, it's just a day before a regional holiday, so shipping times must be +1.

Comment: Awesome.  Can you mark this as the accepted answer?  It helps others who might have the same question quickly find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need a basic update:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET transit_treshold = transit_treshold + 1
WHERE shippingdate_date = '2020-11-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update TableName
set transit_treshold=transit_treshold+1
where shippingdate_date = '20201110'
```

Comment: the is no operators as +=  in sql

Comment: in tsql there is the operator +=,
but in standard SQL yes you are right

Comment: question is not tagged with any direction!!